# Bloquear 'body scroll' quando o LightBox está aberto, mas poder rolar o conteúdo do LightBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, lightbox

Perdoem-me se estiver errado, pois não sei o nome exato do efeito no qual estou à procura, já vi tal efeito em algumas páginas pela Internet mas no momento não tenho nenhum link no qual eu possa usar como exemplo.

Como descrito na pergunta, estou à procura de um efeito que ao clicar num link/botão qualquer, ele abrirá um Lightbox e ao ativar esse Lightbox, o *scroll* da página (ou seja do `body`) deverá ser desativado e um novo *scroll* será adicionado, que representará o *scroll* do conteúdo em aberto do Lightbox.

Portanto se eu mexer no *scroll* com o Lightbox em aberto, o conteúdo que irá rolar será o conteúdo do Lightbox e não o conteúdo da página, até que o Ligthbox seja fechado ou desativado!

Novamente perdoem-me pela falta de exemplos! A pergunta de fato é muito vaga, mas espero que me possam ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma rápida abordagem seria criar uma classe com `overflow:hidden;` responsável por tirar o *scroll* do `body`:

```
.lightbox-open {overflow:hidden;}
```

No qual esta será adicionada à tag `<body>` e accionada/implementada via jQuery quando o lightbox também for accionado. E para o *scroll* do lightbox basta dar um `overflow:auto;` ao elemento que contém o conteúdo do lightbox. Por outras palavras:

```js
$('.dispara').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').show();
    $('body').addClass('lightbox-open');
});
$('.overlay').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').hide();
    $('body').removeClass('lightbox-open');
});
```

```css
body{min-height:1500px;}
.lightbox-open{overflow:hidden;}

.overlay{
    display:none;
    overflow:auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.background-content {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
.dispara {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #006FFF;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="dispara">lança Lightbox</span>
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="background-content">
    ... Corpo do site aqui ...
</div>
```

Comment: Uma ótima forma de fazer o que eu queria!! Agradeço desde já!

Comment: para um melhor posicionamento da pergunta! Que nome você daria esse efeito? Porque pode ser que outras pessoas venham a procurar por tal coisa! E um titulo mais adequado a pergunta poderia ajudar!

Comment: Já editei a sua pergunta para um título mais conveniente, com mais keywords e mais preciso, tanto para pesquisa no SO como para pesquisas em SEO's como o Google ou outro @ivanveloso :)